# after phoenix 1.3 upgrade app.js are not loaded

Tags: javascript, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I updated my phoenix 1.2 to 1.3 follwing [the phoenix upgrade description](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/upgrading-from-120-to-130).

Now `assets/js/app.js` can't be loaded:
`Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'js/app' from '/'`

After debugging the problem, I found that the expected module is `app` not `js/app`.

When I change the module name in the `brunch-config.js` `autoRequire` `modules` to `["app"]` instead of `["js/app"]` it works. I don't understand what is the problem or what I did in my app, that the default settings don't work.

Here my `assets/brunch-config.js`

```
exports.config = {
  // See http://brunch.io/#documentation for docs.
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"

    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css",
      order: {
        after: ["../priv/static/css/app.css"] // concat app.css last
      }
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    assets: /^(static)/
  },

  // Phoenix paths configuration
  paths: {
    // Dependencies and current project directories to watch
    watched: ["static", "css", "js", "vendor"],

    // Where to compile files to
    public: "../priv/static"
  },

  // Configure your plugins
  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/vendor/]
    },
    copycat: {
      "fonts": ["node_modules/font-awesome/fonts"] // copy node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/* to priv/static/fonts/
    },
    sass: {
      options: {
        includePaths: [
          "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets",
          "node_modules/font-awesome/scss"
        ], // tell sass-brunch where to look for files to @import
        precision: 8 // minimum precision required by bootstrap-sass 
      }
    }
  //sass: {
    //   mode: "native" // This is the important part!
    // },
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    globals: {
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    }
  }
};
```

And my `assets/js/app.js` is here:

```
import "phoenix_html"
import "./datetimepicker"
```

thanks for any help, tipps or ideas to understand/solve the problem.

Comment: I do not understand what is your problem: according to what you have said, everything works. Also, it should be `["app"]`, not `["js/app"]`.

Comment: But, if you take a look to the upgrade instructions, it uses the `js/app` name. not the `app`.  I had the same as described in the upgrade instructions. But it doesn't work as described there. I must change the name. The `app.js` is in `assets/js/app.js`. I would expect the `js/app`. How do you come to the conclusion, that it must be `app` not `js/app`. thx

Comment: “How do you come to the conclusion”—easy: `app` works, `js/app` does not.

Comment:  this is not enough for me. I try to understand what is happening here and why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Honestly, you _were not trying to understand_, you just dropped a question in a hope anybody will do a research for you. OK, I did. http://brunch.io/docs/config ⇒ grep for `autoRequire` shows that the expected is `"js/app.js": ["app"]`. I would bet either Chris had an obsolete version of `brunch` while writing this how-to, or like. People make mistakes and all these howtos are not the Gortin’s code of law graved in stone.

Comment: you are an unfriendly person and I hope person like you don't answer to any question, because they don't help, they blame other always for things they don't understand. It is much easier for me to search for a solution than writing a question in english (a language that I don't speak very good). I tried as I could to understand what is happening here. If I'm not experienced as you are, is not a reason to be so arrogant and blaming other for things they don't know. You can not either say anything only, it is working and that is!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is related to the brunch version.
updating brunch to:

**brunch@2.10.10**

solved the problem.